# How can I shorten commands for command line?

Tags: c++, windows, command-line, aliases

I use Windows, and I compile c++ files a lot, I always type

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -O2 -std=c++14 -DALEXPC -o smth smth.cpp
```

So I don't want to always type this whole command is there a way to use some kind of an alias to use it instead of

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -O2 -std=c++14 -DALEXPC -o
```

I tried using doskey but it doesn't work. I wrote

```
doskey runcpp = g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -O2 -std=c++14 -DALEXPC -o
```

and tried to run
`runcpp fast.exe main.cpp`
and the thing is it doesn't read the filenames after the runcpp.

Comment: You should probably read about `make` and makefiles.  The documentation for the GNU version can be found [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).

Comment: `doskey runcpp=g++ $1 -o $2`: `runcpp main.cpp fast.exe`. You have to put positional parameters when defining the macro.

Answer (score 0):

create a text file and copy this line to it.

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wshadow -Wfloat-equal -O2 -std=c++14 -DALEXPC -o %1 %2
```

rename text file to `cmp.bat` and run this command in Command Prompt (CMD) to compile `main.cpp`

```
cmp.bat fast.exe main.cpp
```

Comment: The `.bat` extension is optional so you could just type `cmp fast.exe main.cpp`